# setbounds values are magic numbers

Tags: java, jpanel, magic-numbers

im getting setbounds values as magic numbers. Is there a way to assign all values to a variable rather than assigning a variable to each value?

```
setBounds(10,0,30,200);
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Swing? please provide a context for this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an instance of the [`Rectangle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html) class and pass this as argument and the Rectangle will be defined as final static constant

```
private final static Rectangle xBounds = new Rectangle(10,0,30,200);
```

inside your code

```
setBounds(xBounds);
```